# How do I place a variable from a javascript file in to an element in an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have created a simple quiz in an HTML-document, and I want to display the score in another HTML-document. How do I place a variable from a script file to an element in an HTML file?

This is my Javascript code, with most of the if-statemnts edited out (they are all the same):

```
var score = 0;

function start(){
    if (document.getElementById('radio13').checked){
        score ++;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('radio23').checked){
        score ++;
    }
    var finalscore = score *10;
    var results = "Your score is: " + finalscore + " %.";
    window.location.replace("quizresults.html");
    document.getElementById('presult').innerHTML = results;
}
```

The new page loades, but it is empty. This is the HTML-code for the result-page where I wish to add the score:

```
<div id="main">
        <p id="presult"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can only modify the current document via JavaScript. You could pass the value via the URL and read the value from URL with JavaScript in `quizresults.html`.

Comment: You can use cookies to pass values between pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using a JavaScript [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

On your page with the radio buttons, use this:

```
var score = 0;

function start(){
    if (document.getElementById('radio13').checked){
        score ++;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('radio23').checked){
        score ++;
    }
    var finalscore = score *10;
    var results = "Your score is: " + finalscore + " %.";
    window.location.replace("quizresults.html?" + finalscore);
}
```

Then you need this JavaScript code on the result page:

```js
var finalscore = window.location.search.slice(1);
var results = "Your score is: " + finalscore + " %.";
document.getElementById('presult').innerHTML = results;
```

Comment: That worked. I had to try it a few times, but once I plased it in the <body>, beneath 'presult' it worked just fine.

Comment: Good.  I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

by using `window.location.replace` you're pointing your browser to a new, different page. As such, the last line of your code will not be executed.

To achieve your goal, use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)